# ember linkTo sending empty params in route's model hook

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I have a blog site where going to the url `/posts` should list all posts.  Then clicking a link for `/posts/:post_id` should display the details of that post.  However, when clicking the link, it seems that the `linkTo` is not passing the `:post_id` properly.  Here is my code:

Router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("posts", function() {
    this.resource("post", { path: "/:post_id" }, function() {
      //other routes
    });
  });

  this.route("posts.index", { path: "/" });//Links root url to posts index template
});
```

Routes:

```
/****** Posts ******/
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});

App.PostsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Post.find();
  }
});

/****** Post *******/
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});

App.PostIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});
```

Controllers:

```
/****** Posts ******/
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

});

App.PostsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

});


/****** Post ******/
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

});

App.PostIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

});
```

Posts/Index Template:

```
{{#each post in controller}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{post.name}}</td>
    <td>{{post.title}}</td>
    <td>{{post.content}}</td>
    <td>{{#linkTo post.index post}}View{{/linkTo}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Every time I click the `{{linkTo post.index post}}`, it takes me to the correct url, renders the correct templates (post/index), but nothing displays.  I tried putting a model hook in the PostIndexRoute like this:

```
App.PostIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Post.find(params.post_id);
  }
});
```

But params = `{}`  It has no data in it.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: i'm not sure, but could it be that you need to call `return this.modelFor("post");` in your `PostIndexRoute`'s model hook?

Comment: what does `this.modelFor("post")` do?

Comment: it makes your `PostIndexRoute` use the model of your `PostRoute`, but apparently, your problem could be solved without that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are passing the `post` object you need to `{{linkTo}}` a route that accepts a dynamic URL segment.  In your example `posts.index` doesn't accept a parameter.

```
<td>{{#linkTo post post}}View{{/linkTo}}</td>
```

Here is an example of a way to structure your code to better handle the routing: [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/iwaquv/4/edit)

You should also check out the [Ember.js routing guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/) as an example of how to structure routes.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  I had read the routing guide a few times.  I think this line messed me up: `Transitioning to posts or creating a link to posts is equivalent to transitioning to posts.index or linking to posts.index` So I thought I needed to transition to post.index, not just post